# Is it ok to lower the weights after each set?

Tags: weightlifting, weight-gain, definition

I know you can't overtrain youself too easy but I want to ask if this is ok to do.I do on each muscle group 4 exercises 4 sets of 12 reps and I was thinking that after every set to reduce the weights and do more reps.

For example:

I start doing bench presses with 90 kg,and I do like 10-12 reps after I am exhausted and immediately when I am done I take off some weights and start doing 12 more reps with 40 kg.

To make it more clear I don't do 2 sets with 90 and 2 sets with 40 to be 4 sets,no.I do 4 sets with 90 and 4 sets with 40,just to be clear.

My question is,is it worth it?My main goal is to build muscle and have well defined muscles.

Comment: It's a lot of volume but there is no reason why not, its a very simple drop-set. Personally, I would aim for no more than 25 repetitions of an exercise in total per session. FYI you can over-train yourself.

Comment: I know ,I said you can't over-train too `easy`. :)

Comment: If you want more volume and to include lower weight to develop endurance then look at drop-sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are aiming for drop-sets, you have to do it immediately after the heavy lifting. It's same as cheating reps, or with some support from a spotter. Usually you lower it by 30-40%(depends on individuals how much weights they lower) and do a few more reps. That being said, if you are already done with your 90kg press for 12, dropping it to 40 and doing 4-5 more or even 7 is fine, but if you are aiming 12, it depends on what your point of failure is. If they could sustain another 12 at lower weights or not, only you could find out by doing it.

Personally, I do drop-sets for arms, because it's easy and you can switch to low weights easily on machine or picking up the right dumbbells. In case of bench press, by the time you remove the plates, you'd have already taken 30-40 seconds of break, unless you have a spotter to help you. So it's same as doing another set with lower weight than doing drop-sets(which by definition is doing things right after), unless that's what you aim for. That's more like doing lower reps for the pump, but that can't be categorized as a drop-set.